# Is there a way to have npm publish to a different organization than what it infers from package.json?

Tags: typescript, npm

In an open source project, we plan to publish all Pull Requests to npm using CI/CD. To minimize the risk of supply chain attacks, we want to deploy to a different organization. Is this possible without modifying 'package.json'?

More info: In our case, modifying `package.json` is not easy, there are several interdependent packages in the same repository, managed with the help of lerma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for `npm publish`, there is no way to publish to a different name without modifying the `name` in `package.json`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npm-publish

It would lead to inconsistency between the package and the location in the registry which could have many unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Thank you. We ended up deploying the preview packages to a self-hosted repository, with the same name.